# How to change the view of desktop icons in MATE?

Tags: linux-mint, desktop-environment, desktop, mate-desktop

Desktop icons (for example, symlink to .djvu file or to an image) always have different size. Also the titles of icons interfere with each other and become unreadable.
Could you please explain how to deal with it and make them look like in Windows?

[image]
[image]